# ConflictingBeanDefinitionException even after deleting a class

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am developing a simple maven + spring application and i am getting the following error. It says two of my classes have a conflict. so i deleted the second class but i am still getting the same error. I tried restarting the server but it still says my class exists. Can somebody help?

```
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.nibm.config.RootConfig]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'employeeController' for bean class [com.nibm.hibernate.controller.EmployeeController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.nibm.controller.EmployeeController]
```

Comment: You must have deleted the second class, but it will be still be lying in server's deployment directory.Please try to manually delete Server's deploy directory.Which Server are you using.

Comment: i am using glassfish. None of the classes are to found in web.xml.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve a similar problem by using IntelliJ's function "Rebuild".

The reason was an orphan `.class` file after the corresponding `.java` file had already been deleted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you try and express a little bit more clearly what exactly solved the problem for you?

Answer (score 0):

You get the exception because you have **two** spring beans of the **same** class.

This exception is thrown by 
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner#isCompatible

And looking at that implementation it looks as if you create a bean of type EmployeeController in your RootConfig and additionally by ComponentScan.

To fix the problem remove the bean from the RootConfig or change your ComponentScan, so this bean is not found by it.

You can set a breakpoint in the constructor of EmployeeController. From the stack you can get more information about how and why the bean is created.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and it was because class with same name exist at two locations as mentioned in the Exception itself which are conflicting and after removing one issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same ConflictingBeanDefinitionException..."conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class" when running JUnit tests with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)/ @SpringBootTest from inside Intellij.

Execution via gradle:build of the same tests were running fine.

This began to happen after I had refactored the packaging of several @Components which lead me to believe something was holding a reference to the class under it's previous package name.

No amount of gradle build/clean would seem to clear it.

Doing a Build -> Rebuild Project in IntelliJ was what cleared this issue for me.